# Check category in wp loop

Tags: wordpress

I have a wp query loop. I want to check if  the post belongs to some categories. I can get the category using `the_category()`. I have tried

```
if(the_category()==`car`){do somthing}
```

and how to push all the remaining posts except the car category after to all the 'car' category.

Comment: Do you need to show the posts from the `car` category first, and then all other posts that does not belong to the `car` category?

Comment: @PieterGoosen  yes.exactly

Answer (score 1):

`the_category()` returns many categories.

You might want to try [get the category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

```
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach($categories as $cat) {
  if($cat->cat_name == 'car') {
     // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: and how to push all the remaining posts except the car category after to all the 'car' category. see updated question

Comment: i cant iterate thru the loop. when try echo gettype(the_category());it shows NULL.but echo the_category() has output.

Answer (score 1):

You can run two queries here. The first query gets all posts from the car caregory.  The second query gets all other posts except posts from the `car` category. Just remember to change `CATID FOR CAR` with the id of the car category, and don't forget the minus sign before the ID in the second query. The minus sign means exclude.

You can read more on this in the codex: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$do_not_duplicate = array();

$args = array(
   'cat' => CATID FOR CAR
);

$carargs = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $carargs->have_posts()):

  while ($carargs->have_posts()) : $carargs- >the_post(); 
  $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; 

<----your loop---->

  endwhile; 

endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); 


$args2 = array(
   'cat' => -CATID FOR CAR,
   'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate
);

$restargs = new WP_Query( $args2 );

if( $restargs->have_posts()):

  while ($restargs->have_posts()) : $restargs- >the_post(); 
   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; 

<----your loop---->

  endwhile; 

 endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: i have done this. but pagination problem .i cant use the pagination if there is multiple loop

Comment: see this question of mine also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145556/how-to-show-the-posts-of-some-category-first-and-then-all-other

Comment: Do you need to paginate both queries, or just the second query?

Comment: i want only show 10 posts per page. if first query has more than 10 posts it should have pagination. if first query has less than 10 it doesnt need pagination only second query. see this http://iseas.asia-promos.com/(only demo not functional)  here first query has only one post that has different style.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137040/get-10-posts-from-a-wp-query-if-less-than-10-get-the-remainder-from-elsewhere). It sound that it might be what you are looking for

Comment: that is not accepted answer and if i have 19 posts from first query the next 9 should go to next page and 1 from second query